# Difference between camera LookAt and camera up in Three JS

Tags: three.js

I'm confused about what effect changing the camera.lookAt and camera.up vector has in three.js.
In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvanderdoes/zscjccLs/), I'm having camera.up =  new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1); ,but when I update my controls the rotation of the object is occuring weird.
So, what is the difference between camera lookAt and up direction?

```
var camera, scene, renderer, geometry, material, mesh;

init();
render();

function init() {

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 10;
  camera.position.y = 5;

  // What effect does this have?
  camera.up = new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0);
  camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
  scene.add(camera);

  var axisHelper = new THREE.AxisHelper(5);
  scene.add(axisHelper);

  var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(10, 1);
  scene.add(gridHelper);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function render() {

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at points the camera in a certain direction. up rotates the camera while still looking in that direction. The default up is 0,1,0 which is normal (up for the camera is same up as the sky). But if you want to rotate the camera you can change up, for example up = 1,0,0 would turn the camera 90 degrees to the right

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r110/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r110/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {GUI} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/../3rdparty/dat.gui.module.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 45;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 100;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 10, 20);

  class UpGUIHelper {
    constructor(camera) {
      this.camera = camera;
      this.angle = 0;
    }
    get value() {
      return this.angle;
    }
    set value(v) {
      this.angle = v;
      const r = THREE.Math.degToRad(v);
      this.camera.up.set(Math.sin(r), Math.cos(r), 0);
    }
  }

  function updateCamera() {
    camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

  const gui = new GUI();
  const upGUIHelper = new UpGUIHelper(camera);
  gui.add(upGUIHelper, 'value', -180, 180).name('angle').onChange(updateCamera);

  const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
  controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
  controls.update();

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('black');

  {
    const planeSize = 40;

    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const texture = loader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/checker.png');
    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    const repeats = planeSize / 2;
    texture.repeat.set(repeats, repeats);

    const planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planeSize, planeSize);
    const planeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      map: texture,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);
    mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI * -.5;
    scene.add(mesh);
  }
  {
    const cubeSize = 4;
    const cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(cubeSize, cubeSize, cubeSize);
    const cubeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: '#8AC'});
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, cubeMat);
    mesh.position.set(cubeSize + 1, cubeSize / 2, 0);
    scene.add(mesh);
  }
  {
    const sphereRadius = 3;
    const sphereWidthDivisions = 32;
    const sphereHeightDivisions = 16;
    const sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(sphereRadius, sphereWidthDivisions, sphereHeightDivisions);
    const sphereMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: '#CA8'});
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo, sphereMat);
    mesh.position.set(-sphereRadius - 1, sphereRadius + 2, 0);
    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(0, 10, 0);
    light.target.position.set(-5, 0, 0);
    scene.add(light);
    scene.add(light.target);
  }

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render() {

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
</script>
```

note: up is in world space so (1,0,0) only turns the camera to the right if you're looking down the Z axis. To see this issue, drag the mouse on the scene until the camera is looking 90 degrees to the left or right, the drag the slider. You'll notice all that happens is the camera flips.

If you want to be able to control the camera's rotation around the way it's looking it's probably easier to make the camera a child of some other object. You can then call `lookAt` with that other object and just adjust rotation.z on the camera.

```
  const cameraMount = new THREE.Object3D()
  scene.add(cameraMount);
  cameraMount.add(camera);
  cameraMount.position.set(0, 10, 20);

  // point camera backward because `lookAt` has inconstant
  // behavior. For Cameras it looks toward -Z. For non
  // cameras it looks toward +Z
  camera.rotation.y = Math.PI;  

  const controls = new OrbitControls(cameraMount, canvas);
  controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
  controls.update();
```

Now we have the OrbitControls moving the cameraMount, not the camera. This lets us rotate the camera relative to the mount. We can also call `cameraMount.lookAt` to aim the camera.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r110/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r110/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {GUI} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/../3rdparty/dat.gui.module.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});
  
  const fov = 45;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 100;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);

  class DegRadHelper {
    constructor(obj, prop) {
      this.obj = obj;
      this.prop = prop;
    }
    get value() {
      return THREE.Math.radToDeg(this.obj[this.prop]);
    }
    set value(v) {
      this.obj[this.prop] = THREE.Math.degToRad(v);
    }
  }

  const gui = new GUI();
  gui.add(new DegRadHelper(camera.rotation, 'z'), 'value', -180, 180).name('cam.rot.z');

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('black');

  const cameraMount = new THREE.Object3D()
  scene.add(cameraMount);
  cameraMount.add(camera);
  cameraMount.position.set(0, 10, 20);
  
  // point camera backward because `lookAt` has inconstant
  // behavior. For Cameras it looks toward -Z. For non
  // cameras it looks toward +Z
  camera.rotation.y = Math.PI;  

  const controls = new OrbitControls(cameraMount, canvas);
  controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
  controls.update();


  {
    const planeSize = 40;

    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const texture = loader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/checker.png');
    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    const repeats = planeSize / 2;
    texture.repeat.set(repeats, repeats);

    const planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planeSize, planeSize);
    const planeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      map: texture,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);
    mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI * -.5;
    scene.add(mesh);
  }
  {
    const cubeSize = 4;
    const cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(cubeSize, cubeSize, cubeSize);
    const cubeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: '#8AC'});
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, cubeMat);
    mesh.position.set(cubeSize + 1, cubeSize / 2, 0);
    scene.add(mesh);
  }
  {
    const sphereRadius = 3;
    const sphereWidthDivisions = 32;
    const sphereHeightDivisions = 16;
    const sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(sphereRadius, sphereWidthDivisions, sphereHeightDivisions);
    const sphereMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: '#CA8'});
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo, sphereMat);
    mesh.position.set(-sphereRadius - 1, sphereRadius + 2, 0);
    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(0, 10, 0);
    light.target.position.set(-5, 0, 0);
    scene.add(light);
    scene.add(light.target);
  }

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render() {

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
</script>
```